# Change ComboBox Background and Foreground After Item Selection

Tags: c#, wpf

I have looked through all the answers provided on this website for an answer to my problem and I couldn't find a working solution.

I have a combobox that is bound to a Class using the ItemsSource Property.

The Class Definition is as follows:

```
public class DataSource
{
    public string DisplayField { get; set; }
    public string ValueField { get; set; }
}
```

The ComboBox is bound to display the data using the DisplayMemberPath = "DisplayField" and the SelectedValuePath = "ValueField"... This is done in the code behind and loaded when the Window Loads.

The ComboBox is defined as follows:

```
<ComboBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Margin="5 5 5 0" Name="releaseHoldDropDown" Width="100"/>
```

I need a way to change the background to Green and the Foreground to White if the value of the drop down changes to "Release".

I also need to change the background to Red and the Foreground to White if the value of the drop down changes to "Hold".

FYI: I am using the ExpressionLight.xaml theme to style the application as a whole.

As a side note I also want a way to change the background on ALL my Comboboxes from the Grey to White to make them more readable. So I need to modify the ExpressionLight.xaml but I have no idea which part to edit to make those changes.

Any Help Will be Appreciated.

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why not use a style.trigger?

```
        <ComboBox.Style>
            <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="SelectedValue" Value="Release">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green"/>
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="SelectedValue" Value="Hold">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </ComboBox.Style>
```

this could be a start for you

Comment: I tried out your solution but it didn't work. The background for the ComboBox didn't change. A white border appeared around it but the combo box background itself didn't change.

Comment: I tried your solution with a white background value and it worked. 

I am wondering what do I need to do to make this a generic style in the expression light theme?

Answer (score 0):

Since you only want to change Foreground Colour and not background color(which remains white) so in `releaseHoldDropDown_SelectionChanged` event use

```
private void releaseHoldDropDown_SelectionChanged(object sender, FooBar e)
{
   releaseHoldDropDown.ForeGround = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);

   DataSource ds = (DataSource)releaseHoldDropDown.SelectedItem;

   if (ds.DisplayField == "Release")
        releaseHoldDropDown.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Green);
   else if(ds.DisplayField == "Hold")
        releaseHoldDropDown.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
}
```

and buddy i can help you if you could give me ExpressionLight.xaml. Then only i can help

Comment: I am trying to do this in the xaml. I need the background for the control to be white or transparent to start off with

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to change necessary Colors of Template Controls like below?

```
<ComboBox x:Name="comboBox"
            ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
            Margin="0,0,0,10"
            Background="White">
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid Background="White">
                <TextBlock Foreground="Black" Text="{Binding Name}"/>
            </Grid>    
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```